# php: get a variable inside an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array called `$locations` and this is what it produces if I use `print_r`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [term_id] => 40
        [name] => California
        [slug] => california
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 41
        [taxonomy] => location
        [description] =>
        [parent] => 0
        [count] => 6
     )
)
```

What I need to get from this array is `California` only, but I can't figure out what variable produces that. I tried `$locations->name` and `$locations[name]` but none of those work.

Comment: try $locations[0]->name

Comment: refer to hsz's answer if your array has multiple objects

Comment: Thank you! that did the trick. So i should just ignore the stdClass Object part right? Thats what made me get confused.

Comment: No, see, you have an object inside an array, so that object is the first element of the array. this means you have to access the object first (i.e. `$locations[0]`) and then perform the object manipulation. If you don't intend to have multiple objects in one variable, then really you should be making `$locations` just the object, not an *array* of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$locations seems to be an array (with 1 value, that is an object), so:

```
$locations[0]->name
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
$data = array( /* your data */ );

foreach ($data as $obj) {
  $name = $obj->name; // California - and others in the nest steps 
                      // if array contains more elements
}
```